# map json nods JsonProperty

Tags: java, json, class

I'm using JsonProperty to map json to java Class, my json look like this:

```
{
   "parent1": {
      "parent2": {
          "parent3": { ...(content) }
       }
     }
 }
```

I use java class

```
public class Parent1{
    @JsonProperty("parent1")
       private Parent2 parent1;
}
```

My question: is there a way to cast the content directly in one class instead of creating one for each.
I tried to use :

```
public class Parent1{
@JsonProperty("parent1.parent2.parent3")
     private Object parent1;
}
```

But it always returns null.

Any ideas please?

Thanks!